# How to discard draft of edited Content Item in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms-1.7

In our system, an Editor will constantly make changes/updates to existing Content Items and saving them as drafts.They however do not have the permission to publish updated Content Items. It is the job of a Proofreader to vet through the changes and approve them (publish). If a Proofreader thinks that the changes made to a particular Content Item is not suitable, he/she should be able to discard/reject the draft without affecting the published version of that Content Item prior to changes.

Does Orchard have this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Orchard keeps all versions and i think you can not delete them. this has been asked many times. 
 Do look at modules like 'Version Manager' (out of date) and [Rijkshuisstijl.VersionManager - 0.2](https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Rijkshuisstijl.VersionManager/0.2)
.